# Xcode MapKit: How to trigger event upon specific location enter

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit, core-location

I am working on a location based game where the user upon entering a specified location triggers a video playback. It needs to also have a radius so when user enters the fixed longitude and latitude location event triggers and it needs to use SWIFT.

Got MapKit working just need to know how to plot locations (they won't change) and trigger an event upon user gps location being = to or within set radius of location trigger.

Any advice or tutorials appreciated.

**Edit: How can I add specific regions to monitor in SWIFT. i.e. if user enters region latitude = 1, longitude =-1 then activate function?**

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called: Region Monitoring.

Apple's documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html

> The Core Location framework provides two ways to detect a user’s entry and exit into specific regions: geographical region monitoring (iOS 4.0 and later and OS X v10.8 and later) and beacon region monitoring (iOS 7.0 and later). A geographical region is an area defined by a circle of a specified radius around a known point on the Earth’s surface. In contrast, a beacon region is an area defined by the device’s proximity to Bluetooth low-energy beacons. Beacons themselves are simply devices that advertise a particular Bluetooth low-energy payload—you can even turn your iOS device into a beacon with some assistance from the Core Bluetooth framework.

Tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift

http://shrikar.com/swift-tutorial-corelocation-and-region-monitoring-in-ios-8/

Comment: Thanks, any idea how I would go about assigning each gpx location its own enter / exit function where by entering one location will display set content whereas entering another different specifiable content?